# jQuery AJAX method is calling onchange of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am a little bit confused about the `jQuery AJAX method`, the method is calling when I change something on the screen. May there be some problem asynchronous task?

### This is inside of the jQuery click function:

```
    $("#divModularFenster").html(html).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function () {
                            getJSONObjektList(function (jsonObjekt) {
                            console.log("Callback: " + JSON.stringify(jsonObjekt));
                            // other code
                            var pj = JSON.stringify(jsonObjekt);
                            $.support.cors = true;
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: pj,
                                dataType: "json",
                                processData: false,
                                url: "http://localhost:53658/PostDatenZumWebservice",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    alert("Post erfolgreich: ");

                                }
                            });
                         });                          
                    }
                  }
              });
```

### This method should be call before I send the data to my service:

```
function getJSONObjektList(callback) {

var jsonObjekt = {};
jsonObjekt.ObjektId = [];
jsonObjekt.Selected = [];


doc = Qv.GetCurrentDocument();
doc.GetAllObjects(function (objects) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var obj = objects[i];
        var id = obj.id;
        var caption = obj.caption;
        var type = obj.type;
        var my = obj.my;

        //liste alle verfuegbaren Objekte auf 
        jsonObjekt.ObjektId.push(id);

        if (type === "Statusbox") {
            doc.GetObject(id, function () {
                var statusboxInhalt = this.Data.Rows;
                var utilJSONObjekt;
                for (var j = 0; j < statusboxInhalt.length; j++) {


                    utilJSONObjekt = {};
                    utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektId;
                    utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektWerte = [];

                    var inhalt = statusboxInhalt[j];
                    console.log("Name: " + inhalt[0].text + " Wert: " + inhalt[2].text);


                    var valAr = inhalt[2].text.split(",");
                    for (var k = 0; k < valAr.length; k++) {
                        //liste alle verfuegbaren Objekte auf
                        utilJSONObjekt.SelectedObjektWerte.push($.trim(valAr[k]));

                    }
                    jsonObjekt.Selected.push(utilJSONObjekt);
                    //callback erst starten, wenn alle Elemente durchlaufen worden sind
                    if (j === (statusboxInhalt.length - 1)) {
                        callback(jsonObjekt);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
 });
}
```

Some ideas?

Comment: Can u give the part of the javascrip where you are adding the event handler to call this function ?

Comment: As per your code , you are expecting that on click of OK button AJAX call should happen , right ? Can you tell in detail how it is behaving now , u said change on my page anything , it means any change in control on webpage is calling the AJAX method you hooked up with OK ?

Comment: @Devesh, yeah that right, sorry I was short time away

Comment: I am seeing couple of missing closing brackets and } in your first code. Can u have look into that

Comment: i have also edit my question, you are right there missing some brackets